# How to obtain the reduced model from a subspace projection method?

Tags: ode, numerical-modelling, projection

I have a system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs). It is a large system that has dozens of equations and hundreds of parameters. I wish to reduce its size so it becomes computationally more efficient to simulate, and I'm willing to tolerate some error in the reduced model. So the end result should be a system of ODEs that has a smaller number of equations or parameters.

I can supposedly use methods of subspace projection to obtain a reduced model. For example Principal component analysis / Proper orthogonal decomposition (POD) with the method of snapshots. With this method a **basis** is obtained.

This leads to the following POD algorithm:

1. Input: the data in the matrix $W$ consisting of the snapshots obtianed by simulating the full systems.
2. Calculate the singular value decomposition so that:
   $$W = UVD' .$$
3. Output: The first $l$ columns of $U$ form the reduced subspace and the basis is then $\Phi = [u_1, ... , u_l]$.

If the coefficients of my linear ODE system are in $A$, I can use $\Phi' A \Phi$ to project the system to a reduced subspace and simulate it there.

Having obtained the simulation results $Y$ in the reduced space, I can do $\Phi Y$ to project the results back to the original space.

Now if $A$ models a biological system with meaningful equations, the same cannot be said for $\Phi' A \Phi$. But is there any way $\Phi$ can be used to remove equations or variables from $A$ to obtain a simpler 'real world' system?

**Edit:** I'm not very capable of reading math, so if possible, please explain like I am five.

Comment: I'm not even going to try to explain proper orthogonal decomposition to a five-year-old. How about instead you tell us what you *do* know, and we take it from there? (For example, presumably you learned about subspace projection methods from *somewhere*.)

Comment: @ChristianClason Alright, I understand that the question appears vague. I'll see what more I can edit in. However, I am just learning about projection methods now, as I have only studied biology and programming. I'm reading the book Model Order Reduction - Theory, Research Aspects and Applications as we speak. Just so far I have been handed many ways to calculate POD (among others) and the basis vector, but I can't figure out how to proceed to see biologically meaningful results, if those are even obtainable. Thanks for the comment tho.

Comment: That would help; in particular the ODE system (without too many details) so we can use that in the explanation. In particular, it makes a huge difference whether the ODEs are linear (in which case things are straightforward) or nonlinear (in which case things get difficult)...

Comment: Also, the book you list is a research monograph (or rather, a collection of research/survey articles); a better starting point might be lecture notes, e.g., http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/numerik/personen/volkwein/teaching/POD-Book.pdf, http://www.wire.tu-bs.de/OLDWEB/mameyer/cmr/cmr-main.pdf or http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=165629&fileId=S0962492902000120

Comment: It also makes a difference whether you want to reduce the dimension (number of equations) of the system or build a low-order model of the solution of the ODEs as a function of the parameter (both can be considered as model order reduction, but the approach is quite different).

Comment: @ChristianClason Thank you for the insight, the links seem very helpful. I was considering linear systems, as POD alone does not seem to cut it for nonlinear systems (need eg DEIM). Your last comment has me a bit puzzled, I will look into this in the following days.

Comment: The question boils down to: Do you want a smaller number of *equations* or *parameters*? You can't do both at the same time (although you can do first one, then the other).

Comment: @ChristianClason Well, I managed to do it: find the basis, project the system to the subspace, simulate in lower dimension (less eqs and pars) and project the results back to the original space. But now it seems to me that POD can not give me a simpler system in the original system space like I hoped, is this true? Not sure how to modify the question now..

Comment: You can use the grey `edit` link under your question. You might want to start by describing what you are actually hoping to achieve (e.g., precisely what you mean by "simpler system in the original space"), in terms of the biological application, if necessary. (From the point of view of model reduction, the projected system *is* the simpler system you are looking for.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35070/discussion-between-milez-and-christian-clason).